# Unit Testing Hybrid Angular Js and Angular 8 Application

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm working on a angular js and angular 8 hybrid application. The new components created in angular are downgraded to be used in angular js. Code snippet of module is shown below:

```
@NgModule({
    // Declaration and Imports
    providers:[
        ServiceName,
        // Other Services
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ComponentName,
        // Other components to be used in angular js
    ]
})
export class FeatureModule{
}

declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic
angular.module('app')
   .directive('cmpName', downgradeComponent({component: ComponentName }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
   .factory('serviceName', downgradeInjectable(ServiceName));
```

In `app.module.ts` file, there is following code.

```
// Usual Stuff
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private upgrade: UpgradeModule,
  ) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}
```

Nothing has been updated in component spec file generated by angular cli.

In `tsconfig.spec.json`,

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node", "angular"]
  },
  "files": ["test.ts", "polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

`karma.conf.js` looks like below.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/ProjectFolder'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Now, if I run `npm run test` or `ng test` command to run test suite, I'm getting following error.
`An error was thrown in afterAll Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined ReferenceError: angular is not defined at Module../..path-to-module-file/feature.module.ts.`

How can I resolve this issue? Do I have to mock `angular` variable declared in the module file. Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much of the nitty gritty details, but I run a hybrid application with Webpack and Karma. I downgrade all my components so they can be used in AngularJS, just like you.

The difference is that I have a file called `vendor.ts` that contains AngularJS. I bet you do too, since you only talk about the tests failing, not the product being broken. I have an entry in my Karma config file:

```js
    files: [
      { pattern: "node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-GB.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/intl/locale-data/jsonp/fr-FR.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "static/polyfills.ts", watched: false },
      { pattern: "static/vendor.ts", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js", watched: false },
      { pattern: "static/main.ts", watched: false },
      { pattern: "static/main.test.ts", watched: false },
    ],
```

This tells Karma which files to [watch and serve in the browser](https://karma-runner.github.io/5.2/config/files.html). I think that means that after Webpack compiled these files, Karma-Webpack can find the compiled files and serve them.

Comment: @Rubin Helsloot There is no `vendor.ts` . Can you show me how `vendor.ts` looks or a link to resource? Thanks

Comment: You don't need a `vendor.ts` per se. It's just one file with `import "angular"; import "@angular/common"; ... import "zonejs";` No extra code. Do you have anywhere in your codebase `import "angular"` or `import * as angular from "angular"`?

Comment: We are declaring a vairable as `declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic` in the feature module. I've tried `import * as angular from angular` in the feature module but it breaks both the build and test.

Comment: And `import "angular";`? Check the resulting file, does it contain any AngularJS code?

Comment: It's completely angular. I've added how the feature module file look like in the question itself. Also I've been using angular cli

Comment: Do I have to move the code that downgrades angular 2  code for angular js from feature module? If it is so, how should I go along?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. You don't have any angularJS code in your resulting bundle.